# Using the pyperclip moudel shows gremlin when chinese in clipboard

Tags: python, mojibake, pyperclip

I have an issue that exists only on the MacOs. It works fine on Windows.
I am using python3.

Here is the code:

```
# coding=utf-8
# using address you inputed to open a web map site

import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #get address from command line.
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
     #get address from clip board.
    address = pyperclip.paste()

webbrowser.open('https://ditu.amap.com/search?query=' + address)
```

For example:
copy "New York" works.

But when you copy "和卉家园" which is a Chinese address, it will be a mojibake (garbled text),and this problem exists only in MacOs.

I have no idea how to solve it, please help me ,Thank you!

Comment: The Python versoin is most probably somewhat relevant here...

Comment: thank you , but the python version are newest both on the two OS